# Creating LinkedIn oAuth2.0 Application 2 ledged - application is not allowed to create tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am currently struggling with the oAuth flow at Linkedin. I want to upload and retrieve posts from an application I am developing. I also want to use the 2-ledged authorization flow since this application will run unattended in the cloud.

I already registered the application here: https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps. But when I am trying to access the API or retrieve a token it says that the application is not allowed to create tokens.

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

I do not want to use the 3-ledged-flow since I do not involve user here or cannot.

Is there any solution for this?

BR Lukas

Comment: I also reviewed the Microsoft documentation on this topic and created the application as described...